# Wpf minimizes Window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main Window.Then if you touch settings button a new **modal** Window is shown with some options..Then you click an option and a new Window (lets call it "Settings") is shown.Both windows have as owner the main Window. Our new window(Settings) may open new window having itself as owner for example if you want to add a new staff member.And here is the problem. When you close the new window and then close Settings window the main Window is minimized...  However this doesnt happen if Settings window dont open any other window...

this is how i show the forms

```
 UserForm f = new UserForm();
            f.Owner = this;
            f.Show();
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post a simple code example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: you might also want to add some screenshots in addition to the source code which might help in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you catch when the window is closed (OnFormClose I think) and then unminimise your main window?

Comment: as i found it is a windows bug. The workaround is what you said.

Comment: Do you have a link documenting this bug? It might be helpful to others with this problem in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Use `MainWindow.Activate()` on close of Child Window.

it should work

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and found an apt solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156373/closing-child-window-minimizes-parent).

Set the window owner to null before the Settings window closes.

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Owner = null;
        }
```